# Write a loop code to calculate average 77 different times, using another column as criteria

Tags: python, dataframe, function, loops, average

First of all, that's my first code and question, so sorry for the begginer level here and lack of vocabulary.

I would like to calculate and store in a dataframe the average of the first 5 rows in a column "returns" with column "N" numbered as 1, and afterwards proceeding to calculate the average return of next 5 rows using the same column N numbered as 2, and so on (N goes up to 77). See table below as an example.

Actual data has more than 10.000 lines and column N goes from 1 to 77.

I did prepare a poor code (below as well), but I have two problems with it:

1 - I cannot reference the column N as a loop. I have to type 1 to 77 (so, 77 times) to get all the averages from samples 1 to 77

2 - I cannot write the code to store the output, given also I cannot write the code to repeat itself from N = 1 to 77

In the table below, the desired outcome (ie: average of the top 5 rows for each N), stored in a dataframe, would be: 0,1 (for N = 1) and 0,15 (for N = 2)

[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQDCr.png)

N   Return
1   0.23
1   0.08
1   0.02
1   0.16
1   0.01
1   0.01
1   -0.19
1   -0.14
1   -0.04
1   0.03
2   0.29
2   0.27
2   0.08
2   0.07
2   0.07
2   0.03
2   0.04
2   0.12
2   0.00
2   0.11

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(arq_csv)
ndf = df.loc[df["N"] == 1].head(5)
average = ndf["Return"].mean()
print(average)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd, random

# make dummy data
src = []
for i in range(77):
    for k in range(10):
        src.append([i + 1, random.randint(-10, 10)])
df = pd.DataFrame(src, columns=('N', 'Return'))
print(df)

# process data
df = df.groupby('N').head(5).groupby('N').mean().reset_index()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
     N  Return
0    1    -1.4
1    2    -2.6
2    3     2.0
3    4    -0.6
4    5    -1.0
..  ..     ...
72  73    -2.0
73  74    -0.2
74  75    -2.0
75  76    -7.0
76  77     1.8

[77 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: What an excelent answer! Solved my problem with one line of code basically! Thanks a lot!